# db.get doesn't work if I call it the first time, typescript

Tags: typescript, pouchdb

I have a strange problem:
I have a simple function to get the user information from my DB in myData.ts.

```
test = <any>{};

  getUserInfoFromPouch(filter: string):any{

    this.db.get(filter).then((result) => {
      this.test = result;
    })
    return this.test;
  }
```

and it works ... kinda.

I call the function in my user-data-page constructor:

```
this.userData = this.myData.getUserInfoFromPouch(this.userId);
console.log('------------------t1----------------------------------');
console.log(this.userData);
console.log('------------------t2----------------------------------');
console.log(this.myData.test);
```

but I only get an ampty object back:

```
------------------t1----------------------------------  main.js:62736:9
Object {  }  main.js:62737:9
------------------t2----------------------------------  main.js:62738:9
Object {  }
```

If I call the function again via a button, I get the actual output I would expect.
If I don't call the function in the constructor first, I have to use the button twice to get the data.
That is very confusing. 
I tried many different function spellings like:

```
test = <any>{};

      getUserInfoFromPouch(filter: string):any{

        return this.db.get(filter).then((result) => {
        })
      }
```

or

```
test = <any>{};

      getUserInfoFromPouch(filter: string):any{

        this.db.get(filter).then((result) => {
        return result;
      })
      }
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for help.

Btw. I Have only one record in the database. (for test purposes)

**Edit:**
Okay, I tried the function like this:

```
async getUserInfoFromPouch(_id: string){


    try {
      this.test = await this.db.get(_id);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('------------------t3----------------------------------');
    console.log(this.test);

  }
```

and I call the function in the constructor of my user page, like before.
After I called the function, I fill my userdata with the test var from the function:

```
    this.myData.getUserInfoFromPouch("userinfo");
    this.userData = this.myData.test;
    console.log('------------------t1----------------------------------');
    console.log(this.userData);
```

but the userData is empty. And I get the console.output of the function AFTER I did:

```
this.userData = this.myData.test;
```

I'm doing something pretty wrong ;-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: mhm I tried a async aproach, but it still doesn't work. If I call the function, I get the expected data, but for some reasons, I get the data ( if I call it in this order): 
this.myData.getUserInfoFromPouch(this.userId);
    this.userData = this.myData.test;
    

    console.log('------------------t1----------------------------------');
    console.log(this.userData);
after  the console.log(this.userData);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it solved the problem with promises.

```
 this.myData.getDocumentById('userInfo').then(res=>{
      if (res!=undefined){
        this.userData=res;
      } 
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log('userInfo-error:  ', err)
    });
```

Now it works as it should 
my getDocumentById function locks like this:

```
 getDocumentById(id: string):any {
    this.syncTwoWay();
    return this.db.get(id).then((doc) => {
      return doc;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('getDocumentById' + err);
    });
  }
```